# Warhammer 40k Retribution, unable to connect for coop play

Tags: technical-issues, networking, warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

My friend and I are trying to play Warhammer 40k Retribution together in campaign coop. When one of us accepts the others' Steam invite, the connecting player sees "Connecting..." then "Connection timed out".  The other player sees no indication that anyone is connecting.

We're on a lan, both connected to the same router.  Both of us have version the latest version currently (3.12.05944), both of us have all firewalls disabled on our machine (though we're behind a NAT). The NAT does support uPNP.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kinda solved itself for me, I bought an SSD and reinstalled Win7 and Retribution onto it and suddenly it worked. I wish I had better information for anyone else with this problem though.

Comment: you should really add that as a question, then mark it as the answer. That way, if other people find this question, they'll know it worked for you...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point about adding something as a question. The reason I haven't added an answer is that "buy a new hard drive and reinstall windows" isn't super helpful.